# Flexboxes overlapping instead of pushing aside?

Tags: css, flexbox

If you hover the green box at:

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/YS5QN/3/

It will expand and squeeze out the blue box. Is there a way to make it overlap the blue box instead, so the blue box remains in place?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column_1"></div>
    <div class="column_2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
}
.column_1 {
    flex: 1;
    height: 60px;
    background: blue;
}
.column_2 {
    width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
    background: green;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.column_2').hoverIntent({
    over: function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: '100%'
        }, 500);
    },
    out: function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: '120px'
        }, 500);
    },
    timeout: 300
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are mis-using `display:flex`.
Maybe try using `width:calc()` and `position:absolute`;

Try this out:

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YS5QN/4/)

Also, I wanted to show you how you can animate that box without using jQuery

```
.column_2 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
    background: green;

    -webkit-transition: 500ms width;
    -moz-transition: 500ms width;
    -ms-transition: 500ms width;
    -o-transition: 500ms width;
    transition: 500ms width;
}

.column_2:hover {
    width: 100%;
}
```

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YS5QN/6/)

Comment: Is there an alternative to position absolute? It doesn't seem to work very well with jQuery Mobile: http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/YS5QN/7/

Comment: No, you have to use `absolute` in order for the right box to overlap the other. jQuery Mobile isn't so much your problem as this: `$(document).on('pagecontainershow')...` Take it out and it works: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YS5QN/8/)

Comment: Is there absolutely no other way of doing this? The abs pos thing is causing some major headache: https://github.com/WickyNilliams/headroom.js/issues/72