# CSS Flexbox - accomplish one div overlapping another

Tags: css, flexbox

Is there a way to overlap a `div` with another using flexbox? Both `divs` have a fixed width. The overlapping should happen when the browser screen is smaller than the width of both divs. I created a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/wecocayefe/1/edit?html,css,output. The `div` with the class .right should overlap the `div` with the class .left.

Any tipp, hint or solution  would be highly appreciated!!!

Markup:

```
<div class=container>
   <div class="left">
     <p>Lorem....</p>
   </div>
   <div class="right">
     <p>Lorem ....</p>
     <p>Lorem.....</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
   background: green;
   width:300px;
} 
.right {
   background: red;
   width:300px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsbin.com/vitalatapi/2/edit Is this what you're trying to achieve? Or completely overwrite it? I think that could be achieved with `position: absolute` or something.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23745180/1654265

Comment: Ok, sorry. Added the relevant markup and CSS. @Vlad: The divs should not wrap the text if the width changes and instead overlay the text from the other div.

Comment: @knoefel your remark sounds like you don't want flex boxes.

Comment: @mr-lister i'm totally open for alternative ideas or solutions. but the requirements (dynamic height for both divs -> that's why choose flexbox, fixed width and also the overlaying function) made other options impossible until now.

Comment: Flexbox may not be the best tool here. Flexbox tries to keep children elements separated, rather than combining them. So perhaps use media queries and if the 2 divs need to stack you can put them in a container div with position:relative and then set positon:absolute for the 2 child divs.

Comment: I found a solution by adding a wrapper for each div. Unfortunately it doesn't work in IE (surprise!). Here is the updated JSBin: http://jsbin.com/meniyopigo/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Does anybody have an idea why it isn't working in IE? I tested in IE11.